# Creating random outgoing and incoming calling using Sinch or Twilio?

Tags: ios, sinch

I'm working on an iOS app that pairs callers randomly (VOIP), like Chatroulette, but it seems that Sinch's iOS SDK requires one person to directly call the other using their phone number or username.

What is the best way to generate this type of call pairing?

This app would work similarly to Wakie, the ios app.

Answer (score 1):

You would keep track of you own users that can be what ever and you just do a random function on your server side that returns a user name and then connect the user to that user name